# How to exclude one min and one max number?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have list:

```
numbers = [2,3,1,6,5]
```

And I must remove one min and one max number:

```
sorted(numbers)[1:-1]
```

And this is ok, but I want get additional information - position of removed numbers in original list:

```
remains = sorted(numbers)[1:-1]
min_number_position = 2
max_number_position = 3
```

How to do it? Numbers can be repeated.

Comment: You want a pure python solution? Or can you use libraries like numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `min` and `max` functions in couple with `index` method of list to get position:

```
min_position = numbers.index(min(numbers))
max_position = numbers.index(max(numbers))

del numbers[min_position]
del numbers[max_position]
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure python solution by creating arg sorted array (as created by [`numpy.argsort()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)) . Example -

```
numbers = [2,3,1,6,5]
argsorted = sorted(range(len(numbers)),key=lambda x:numbers[x])
maxpos,minpos = argsorted[-1],argsorted[0]
remains = [numbers[i] for i in argsorted[1:-1]]
```

Demo -

```
>>> numbers = [2,3,1,6,5]
>>> argsorted = sorted(range(len(numbers)),key=lambda x:numbers[x])
>>> argsorted
[2, 0, 1, 4, 3]
>>> maxpos,minpos = argsorted[-1],argsorted[0]
>>> remains = [numbers[i] for i in argsorted[1:-1]]
>>> remains
[2, 3, 5]
>>> maxpos
3
>>> minpos
2
```

---

If you can use `numpy` library, this can be easily done using `array.argsort()` . Example -

```
nnumbers = np.array(numbers)
nnumargsort = nnumbers.argsort()

minpos,maxpos = nnumargsort[[0,-1]]
remains = nnumbers[nnumargsort[1:-1]]
```

Demo -

```
In [136]: numbers = [2,3,1,6,5]

In [137]: nnumbers = np.array(numbers)

In [138]: nnumargsort = nnumbers.argsort()

In [139]: minpos,maxpos = nnumargsort[[0,-1]]

In [140]: remains = nnumbers[nnumargsort[1:-1]]

In [141]: remains
Out[141]: array([2, 3, 5])

In [142]: maxpos
Out[142]: 3

In [143]: minpos
Out[143]: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> sorted(enumerate(numbers), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
[(2, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (4, 5), (3, 6)]
```

The rest is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function and return the index of max and min with `list.index` method :

```
>>> def func(li):
...     sorted_li=sorted(li)
...     return (li.index(sorted_li[0]),sorted_li[1:-1],li.index(sorted_li[-1]))
...     
>>> min_number_position,remains,max_number_position=func(numbers)
>>> min_number_position
2
>>> remains
[2, 3, 5]
>>> max_number_position
3
```

In python 3.X you can use unpacking assignment :

```
>>> def func(li):
...     mi,*re,ma=sorted(li)
...     return (li.index(mi),re,li.index(ma))
```